# Help and Improvement queue needs "Looks OK"?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, help-improvement

I just started participating in the [Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper) queue, and already stumbled across several posts that I would personally not consider in need of editing. I suspect most often it is a case of the post being edited by the author or someone else in the meantime (I know of no way to verify that though).

A few examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/10342472
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/10355589

But this is not about this particular post but rather in general about posts that end up in the queue and are (no longer) in a severe need of improvement. **For the sake of this discussion, consider a post where there is nothing more to fix anymore** (or is it not possible that a post is marked as "requires editing" and then edited before it gets to be reviewed?).

What is an appropriate action to take with such post? I "Skip" now, but if everyone did that, such post would be stuck in the queue, or wouldn't it? Do we need a "Looks OK" button in this queue for such cases?

Please don't consider this a feature request but rather seeking of guidance / best practice and explanation behind this queue's workings.

Comment: well lets say it like this: the queue is not full of old questions.

Comment: @Gimby is that to say I should just skip and not worry about it, and there's some "magic" that takes care of this? If so, I would still be interested in understanding what that "magic" is.

Comment: That is to say apparently -something- is already doing what you want to achieve, so skipping doesn't hurt :) I'm also curious though, SO is a mysterious machine. What I do know is that certain actions influence how questions are queued - I can guess that when a question is edited by any means it is taken out of this particular queue and stuck back into another one. But you seem to be describing cases where this hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Skipping does, as far as I know, eventually remove items from the queue; this has been mentioned a few times by Shog et al.

Answer (score 4):

99.9% of the posts in the "Help and Improvement" queue *can* and should be edited. I guess that posts in this queue are coming from the ["Triage"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/) queue - There we had the option to click "Looks OK".

The [example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/10342472) you've linked us can have many edits:

- "java" → "Java"
- setContext() → `setContext()`
- maybe also NullPointerException →  `NullPointerException`
- I also like to sql → SQL

If you feel nothing can be done to this post, skip it. I'm sure there'll be another user who'll find something to edit in the post and leave helpful and informative comment to the OP.

I think that adding "Looks OK" button will make some of us take less time when reviewing the post in deep details and maybe we'll pay less attention because at first glance everything might seem OK.

Comment: That puts it in a painfully clear perspective. Does that mean that if a question is edited through this queue it is not instantly taken out of it, to give others the chance to also take a stab at it? The way you describe it here I would hope not, that makes it a lower barrier to contribute in the queue. Doing the proper edits down to the fine details is something very heavily influenced by time pressure.

Comment: @Gimby My impression is that H&I is one edit and out, which certainly puts me off of visiting it as regularly as other queues since I know it's a significant time commitment.

Comment: This queue is meant to help users improve their posts by giving meaningful message and fixing format, grammar or whatever you feel should be fixed as an advanced member. If you don't feel ready to do that for some posts, simply don't (that's why you should skip and not "Looks OK" if it was there).

Comment: While I agree those are possible improvements, are they really significant enough to warrant "**requires** editing"? I would like to *not* focus on the example given as I indicated, but rather seek guidance for the general case where I can't spot any significant issues.

Comment: @jiritousek We are aiming (and this is happening) for making Stack Overflowthe first resource for programming questions. I would do anything (including minimal changes) if this helps improving even one letter of the post.

Comment: @JiriTousek skip is the guidance. The fact that you can't see anything is not proof there is nothing to be seen. And in my case the guidance is: don't review there.